# new type consists of decimal and double

Tags: c#, algorithm, oop, types

In my application I have calculations that need precise as decimal and data range as double.
If I use decimal, calculations cause overflow and if I use double, the calculations cause precise lost.
What's the solution?

Comment: If you need the accuracy of `decimal` then use you should use `decimal`. How and where do the calculations overflow? Perhaps you should look at solving that issue directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this fits for you:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/88980/Rational-Numbers-NET-4-0-Version-Rational-Computin
Anyway you can use it as start-point to build your own "high precision floating point number". Do not forget anything you'll use it'll be **really** slower than primitive types.